# Фон блока пропадает при ширине разрешения экрана ниже 500 пикселей

Tags: html, css, frontend

Есть блок div с картинкой на фоне. При изменении ширины она тянется, но если ширина становится меньше 500 пикселей, то пропадает вообще. Как можно исправить?

```
<div class="banner">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <div><img src="img/suns1.jpg"  alt="" /></div>
        <div><img src="img/suns1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><img src="img/suns1.jpg"  alt="" /></div>
        <div><img src="img/suns1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        <div><img src="img/suns1.jpg"  alt="" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

сss

```
.banner{
    height: 301px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../img/gradient_menu.png);
    min-width: 500px;
}


.wrapper{
    width: 620px;
    height: 260px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px 3px black;    
}
.wrapper img{
    width: 620px;
    height: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код в студию!

Comment: без кода очень сложно угадать, что у вас там, дополните вопрос кодом, добавьте [mcve]